# Determining the dimension of a set of transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V,W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces and let $U \subseteq V$.

Define $E = \{ T \in hom (V,W) | U \subseteq Ker(T) \}$ and

$E' = \{ T \in hom (V,W) | Ker(T) ⊆ U  \}$.

Are these sets subspaces and if so what are their dimensions?

**My attempt:** Let $T , S \in E$.

Let $T, S$ be represented by the matrices $A, B$ with respect to the standard basis $(Mm*n)$.

If $U \subseteq Ker(T)$ then $\forall u∈U Au = 0, Bu = 0$.

Then $(A+B)(u) = Au + Bu = 0$.

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}, (cA)(u) = c(Au) = 0$.

Then $E$ is a subspace since it is closed under addition and multiplication.

$\dim E =\dim V - \dim U$; Im not sure if this is correct and if so how to prove it.

$E'$ is not a subspace.

Let $A=
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   { - 1} & 1 & 0  \\
   0 & 1 & 0  \\
   0 & 1 & 0  \\
\end{array}} \right)$
, $B=
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 1 & 0  \\
   0 & 1 & 0  \\
   0 & 1 & 0  \\
\end{array}} \right)$

and suppose $U = Sp\{(0,0,1)\}$, so $E'$ isn't closed under addition

Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow your argument that $E'$ isn't closed under addition.  Isn't the sum $$\begin{array}{ccc}0&2&0\\0&2&0\\0&2&0\end{array}$$ and doesn't that take $(0,0,1)$ to zero?

Comment: The dimension of $\text{hom}(V,W)$ should be $\text{dim}(V) \times \text{dim}(W)$ so I don't think $\text{dim}(E) = \text{dim}(V) - \text{dim}(U)$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, regarding your first comment, the null of the addition matrix is now {(0,0,1),(1,0,0)} which is not a subset of U.

Comment: I think you want to say that E is a subspace of hom(V,W) [instead of a subset], and you can find its dimension by taking a basis for U, extending it to a basis for V, and then using a basis for W to find a basis for E.  You are right that E' isn't closed under addition, but I agree with @GregoryGrant that your example doesn't show this.

Comment: I see what you you're saying now.

Comment: @user84413 can you take another look at the example please, or correct me? the new addition matrix has a null of  {(0,0,1),(1,0,0)}. then this addition matrix is not a subset of U thus it isn't a member of E'. any ideas regarding how to prove dimE?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mistaken -- your example does show that E' isn't closed under addition.